# posting objectId in postman

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose, schema, postman

I'm trying to post this json to an API using postman

```
{
"order" : [{ "mealId": 562b2649b2e70464f113c04d, "quantity": 4}],
"service_id" : 562b2649b2e70464f113c04d,
"dest" : "Allabama",
"active": false
}
```

but I keep getting this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token b
    at Object.parse (native)
    at parse (C:\nodeprojects\foodDelivery\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:88:17)
    at C:\nodeprojects\foodDelivery\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:108:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\nodeprojects\foodDelivery\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)
    at done (C:\nodeprojects\foodDelivery\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\nodeprojects\foodDelivery\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:308:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

its a nodejs api with mongoose. 
This is the schema for the json object

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var OrdersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
order : [{ mealId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, quantity: Number}],
service_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
dest : String,
orderTime : {type:Date, default:Date.now},
completeTime : {type:Date, default:Date.now},
active: Boolean,
});
```

So in short the problem is when I try to pass the ObjectId, It stops reading after the "562" and sees the 'b' as an illegal character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must quote the strings:

```
{
"order" : [{ "mealId": "562b2649b2e70464f113c04d", "quantity": 4}],
"service_id" : "562b2649b2e70464f113c04d",
"dest" : "Allabama",
"active": false
}
```

Comment: When I try that I get a "unexpected string" error because it's expecting an ObjectId not a string

Comment: Thanks! the first time I tried it I had accidentally left out a comma after one of the entires. Placing them in quotes fixed it. Thanks again!

Comment: I am getting {000000000000000000000000} in ObjectId field when I pass values like this from postman.... Am using c# driver ..  any solutions ?

Comment: How can I pass array of object IDs ?

Comment: Hi, I receive Null for the id value if my variable contains "Id". When change it to "service" it gets fixed. Do you know how to pass that?

Answer (score 1):

receive the _id object as a string and not as ObjectId,
when you got this id create new mongo.driver ObjectId

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostExample(string idinstring)
 {
         ObjectId d=new ObjectId(idinstring);
  }
```

Comment: The combination of these two solutions are great. Thanks!